# Java Sending Email to Message Transfer Agent

Tags: java, email, smtp

As per title. 
On the typical email sending in Java Mail, there is a SMTP server to connect to with email/password for authentication.

However, I am given a task of sending email to a MTA server provided and 
this MTA server I am working on has no username / password configured for sending email.
So, I tried removing the authentication part of username/passowrd of typical SMTP email sending, and I got AuthenticationException upon initiating email sending.

Suppose you guys have any insights, helps or even website that gives tutorial to such mail sending mechanism? Thanks for any guidance

Comment: check if there is any email password on the server for which authentation has been disabled like a admin user or a super user. it all depends on the server configuration and i guess this can be done by admin guys of your team. check with them first

Comment: Hi @vikeng21, in other words, you mean there is an email (as sender) without need of password to be used with?

Comment: the Java mail api requires a username and password for email which can be optional also. check the api docs for anonymous authentication. i guess you will have to do configuration on the server for your case. may be go through the server docs for the host configuration